# Hibernate ElementCollection child delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I've got this mapping in my UserPO entity :

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "department") })
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "mission")
private Map<MissionPO, DepartmentListPO> departmentsByMission = new HashMap<MissionPO, DepartmentListPO>();
```

I use a table DepartmentList and DepartmentListPO as a `Map<MissionPO, List<DepartmentPO>>` seems not to be an option with Hibernate (or JPA)

So far so good, a user can be given a mission restricted to a list of department.

Exemple :
Tom has mission 1 on department 10 and 11

My problem is that if I remove a mission :

```
departmentsByMission.remove(mission)
```

The `role` row that linked User/Mission/DepartmentList isn't deleted.
I read a lot of threads and it seems bulk delete isn't possible with `ElementCollection`.

I tried to use a constraint `ON CASCADE DELETE` on the role table on the DepartmentList foreign key, but this seems to be the inverse of what I want. Deleting a DepartmentList will delete the role.

So What I would like is to do something like `entityManager.remove(departmentList)` in the `removeMission`method of the `actor`.

Unfortunately it seems that the `PersistentContext` can't be put in the `User` entity.

So I'm a bit confused what would be the solution, knowing I would like to avoid a database trigger.

Thanks for any solution, I'm really stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is caused by the data model rather than an issue with ORMs, hibernate or JPA.  From my experiences, it seems like this is an unconventional approach.

A mission could be its own entity, which contains a department property that also exists as an entity.  When creating a map of missions, it would be more useful to use its surrogate key from the database as the key for the map.  I would encourage you to spend time reviewing your data model for additional entities that need to be mapped.

Comment: Mission should be independant from department as the same mission could be given to different User on different department. And a mission can live without being given to a user. But you're right, maybe I could create an entity for the Role table

Comment: In that case I would include a User property within mission.  But do you get the bigger point I'm trying to make?  Using a surrogate key for these tables will make your life easier.

Comment: Ok I got it now, I'm not expert in English so I "bypassed" surrogates without really noticing it was important. I will do that but it seems that using Map and ElementCollection is the point of my deletion problem no ?

Comment: Yes, by surrogates I mean a generated primary key by an autoincrement field, sequence or trigger.

Comment: I went your way and modified the model using generated primary keys. It's as you say a lot easier now to control my Hibernate model.